# Create a barh graph with mapped colors inside using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I'm tring to create a graph that has different bars with different colors inside:

5 green red green red red
4 green green green red red
3 green red green green red
2 green red green red green
1 green red green red red
0   1    2    3    4   5

Or maybe find another solution for creating a graph in this way.

I have reached the point where i build this graph:

```
def generate_graph(day_check):
    try:
        # Organize data by day
        daily_data = {}
        for timestamp, status in day_check:
            day = timestamp.split('-')[2].split(' ')[0]
            if day not in daily_data:
                daily_data[day] = {'0': 0, '1': 0}
            daily_data[day][status] += 1

        # Plot the horizontal bar chart
        days = list(daily_data.keys())
        days.reverse() # Reverse the order of days
        zeros = [daily_data[day]['0'] for day in days]
        ones = [daily_data[day]['1'] for day in days]

        fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 8))


        bar1 = ax.barh(days, zeros, 1.0,  label='Errors', color='red')
        bar2 = ax.barh(days, ones, 1.0,  label='Success', color='green', left=zeros)

        ax.set_xlabel('Checks')
        ax.set_ylabel('Day')
        ax.legend()
        plt.savefig(f'graph.png')
```

where:

```
day_check_data = [
    ("2023-01-01 12:30:00", '0'),
    ("2023-01-02 14:45:00", '1'),
    ("2023-01-03 10:15:00", '0'),
    ("2023-02-03 12:30:00", '1'),
    ("2023-02-04 14:45:00", '0'),
    ("2023-02-05 10:15:00", '1'),
    ("2023-03-05 12:30:00", '0'),
    ("2023-03-06 14:45:00", '1'),
    ("2023-03-07 10:15:00", '0'),
    ("2023-04-07 12:30:00", '1'),
    ("2023-04-08 14:45:00", '0'),
    ("2023-04-09 10:15:00", '1'),
]
```

0s are green 1s are red.

But in this case it will create a graph with lines red and green based on total amount of 0s and 1s per day.

Something like, create a square for every 0s and 1s, color the square red if it's 0, green if it's 1, I would like to have the red and green based on the day status.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to visualize it, you could create a tkinter canvas.
There is a problem with vertical text, but there are workarounds.

There are ways to convert a canvas into an image if you need to store it.
This needs fine tuning but might give you a bit more flexibility

```
import tkinter as tk


def vertical_text(text: str) -> str:
    text_list = [character for character in text]
    return '\n'.join(text_list)


day_check_data = [
    ("2023-01-01 12:30:00", '0'),
    ("2023-01-02 14:45:00", '1'),
    ("2023-01-03 10:15:00", '0'),
    ("2023-02-03 12:30:00", '1'),
    ("2023-02-04 14:45:00", '0'),
    ("2023-02-05 10:15:00", '1'),
    ("2023-03-05 12:30:00", '0'),
    ("2023-03-06 14:45:00", '1'),
    ("2023-03-07 10:15:00", '0'),
    ("2023-04-07 12:30:00", '1'),
    ("2023-04-08 14:45:00", '0'),
    ("2023-04-09 10:15:00", '1'),
]

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('580x320')

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=800, height=600)
canvas.pack()

x = 50
y = 50
y_offset = 80
bar_width = 30
bar_height = 100
space = 2

for day in day_check_data:
    timestamp = day[0].split(' ')[0]
    value = day[1]
    color = 'red' if value == '1' else 'green'
    canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, x + bar_width, y + bar_height, fill=color)
    label = canvas.create_text(
        x + bar_width / 2,
        y + bar_height + y_offset,
        text=vertical_text(timestamp),
        font='Consolas 10 bold'
    )
    x += bar_width + space

root.mainloop()
```